# How to develop in the following environment

Tags: 2010, deployment, solution-deployment

1. Production has 10 servers, 8 app servers, 2 front end.  Its own active directory
2. Testing has almost the same.  Its own active directory

The problem is that at the moment, in the current company they are developing directly on testing, because there was only one developer.

Now, we are 2 developers and soon more people will come in.
So, the infrastructure people installed a development environment, with 2 app servers, 1 front end server, and 1 active directory.  We will create 2 users in AD with remote desktop access to the servers.

We dont have TFS, they have tortuise.

The question is how can 2 developers work together in the same solution in the same DEV environment,and maybe they will deploy the same solution multiple times a day.

One developer might have assigned some issues that are developed in the same solution, the other developer is working too.

I need to define a plan for this, so it doesnt become a problem.

Need suggestions in what would you do, propose, suggest.

Comment: Just wondering, why don't you develop using virtual machines ? (vmware or so)? Thats how i develop. We all have our own machine, so no conflicts occur. Apart from that I have no experience with developing with different users on the same machine...

Comment: all of them are virtual machines already, I meant dev and test environments

Comment: My dev environment is my virtual machine... Thats my point

Comment: not easy if you need to develop a lot of features against active directory, but at the end, its not a problem in a corporate environment, so we have also ADs in virtual servers for each developer.

Comment: Im developing the intranet of a multinational located in: USA, Canada, India, China, Belgium, ... We used to work with 8 developers, each on our own virtual machine. Atm i am the only developer, but still I am using my own Virtual Machine...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I strongly recommend that each dev has it's own installation. It could be a Virtual machine (single machine with AD, SQL and SharePoint). It looks like your company is not shy on resources so it might be possible for you.

2 people (or more!) on the same box will lead to frequent delays as you deploy/recycle, hook the debugger, or if you want to test a different branch or even work on a different project. VMs are so cheap nowadays if you have a good desktop you can run it there with VMWare Player.

I would promote your current Testing to PreProduction, since it almost matches prod hardware-wise (and setup-wise I assume), and make your current Dev into Testing/Integration/QA so you would have a very nice setup:

- Production
- PreProduction
- QA
- Dev

Comment: We mostly never see Test environments with the same architecture as PROD/QA. Here TEST = 1 server, QA = PROD = multiple servers

Comment: Indeed, just had a small meeting, I didnt remember about the problem of debugging at the same time. at the end we decided to go for each developer will have its own small virtual farm. Sharepoint, AD, Sql Server. and both developers will connect to a source control.  Each one will deploy freely in its own environment, if for any reason, one needs a component from the other, it will be just to checking the source code, the other will get latest version and deploy as well.  perfect solution for us....

Comment: Louis' model is much like ours. All of our people do their own dev on a local VM that they maintain. Solutions then get pushed to Test--there's no actual development on the test/dev environment.

Comment: I agree. That's the safest way.